# Returning a length of a string up until the specified character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string that is test = `bcdefaghijklmnaopqrstuavasdfawefafw`

I'm trying to find the length of a string up until it encounters the first 'a', which is len(bcdef) = 5.

I was wondering if there is a simple built-in function that does this?

What I have so far is `len(test.partition('a')[0])`, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: err `s.index("a")` gives the first position of `a`. Unless it's not in the string...

Comment: ahahahahhaha I forgot about that... thanks

Comment: use `s.find("a")` it's even better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len(test.partition('a')[0])` is indeed complex & underperformant.

I'd use `str.index` with an exception catch in case the letter isn't in the string, in which case, the function could return `-1` for instance (or length of the string, it's a convention. `str.find` returns `-1` when substring not found).

```
s="bcdefaghijklmnaopqrstuavasdfawefafw"

def slen(s,c):
    try:
        return s.index(c)
    except ValueError:
        return -1  # could return len(s)
```

(`str.index` returns the position of the *first* occurrence of the char/substring in the string or throws an exception if not present)

Alternative: use `s.find("a")`, which does exactly the same thing, without the hassle of handling the exception (it returns `-1` when not found)

Comment: in case of `ValueError` I would get `len(s)` (*"Returning a length of a string up **until** the specified character"*)

Comment: yeah it's a matter of convention. `str.find` returns `-1` when substring not in list. Wait! we could use `str.find` directly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.index("a")` or `str.find("a")`.

Both return the index of the first occurence of the character. 
The difference between them is `index()` raises an error if the character is not found. `find()` returns -1 when the character is not found. Which one to use depend on your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You use index+1

Index returns the index of a particular character(or the length of the string till a particular character -1)

```
test = "bcdefaghijklmnaopqrstuavasdfawefafw"
len = test.index('a')+1
```